# Linux FHS: /srv vs /var ... where do I put stuff?

Tags: linux

My web development experience has started with Fedora and RHEL but I'm transitioning to Ubuntu. In Fedora/RHEL, the default seems to be using the /var folder while Ubuntu uses /srv.

Is there any reason to use one over the other and where does the line split? (It confused me so much that until very recently, I thought /srv was /svr for server/service)

My main concern deals with two types of folders

- default www and ftp directories
- specific application folders like:

  1. samba shares (possibly grouped under a smb folder)
  2. web applications (should these go in www folder, or do can I do a symlink to its own directory like "___/www/wordpress" -> "/srv/wordpress")

I'm looking for best practice, industry standards, and qualitative reasons for which approach is best (or at least why its favored).

Comment: Maybe this other question helps you: http://serverfault.com/questions/102569/should-websites-live-in-var-or-usr-according-to-recommended-usage/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This stems from [LSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) which says "`/var` contains variable data files. This includes spool directories and files, administrative and logging data, and transient and temporary files." but says this for `/srv`: "`/srv` contains site-specific data which is served by this system."

SuSE was one of the first disto's that I used that kept webroot's in `/srv` - typically Debian/Ubuntu/RHEL use `/var/www` - but also be aware that if you install a web application using yum or apt then they will likely end up in `/usr/share`. Also the [packaging guidelines for Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#No_Files_or_Directories_under_.2Fsrv.2C_.2Fopt.2C_or_.2Fusr.2Flocal) say that a "package,  once installed and configured by a user, can use `/srv` as a location for data. The package simply must not do this out of the box".

On balanced reflection I would say keep to `/var/www` - or you can do both by making `/var/www` a symlink to `/srv/www`. I know that on oracle RDBMS systems that I build I often create `/u01` `/u02` etc as symlinks to `/home/oracle`. The reason for this is that many DBA's expect to find things in /u01 and many others expect `/home/oracle`. The same can be said of Sysadmins in general - some will instinctively look in `/var/www` and some in `/srv/www` while others like myself will grep the apache config for the `DocumentRoot`.

Hope this provides some guidance for you.

Comment: I usually put "served" resources under /srv, mostly for storage and backup reasons. This way served data can be in a storage pool different from system managed files such apt cache and logs, and it's easier to accomodate more space if needed.

Comment: Using the `/srv` partition is particularly useful when you have separate drives mounted on `/var` and `/srv` and do not want your logging to impact your IO. It is worth mentioning that Apache comes with `Directory` directives for `/srv` as well, they are just commented out.

Comment: Here are some links to the documentation of the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy: For /srv http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/srv.html and for /var http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html